# wso2 is - roles not visible in embedded ldap

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using softerra LDAP browser to view the users configured in WSO2 IS. I can view the users. But I couldn't see the corresponding roles configured.

I use the principal uid=admin,ou=system

How can I view the roles that are mapped to the users ? Aren't they available in LDAP ?

Answer (score 0):

Roles in WSO2 Identity Server is mapped to groups in LDAP. Please check for groups instead of roles in LDAP